# Error: failed to find target with hash string 'android-14' in:Open Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk

I know this question has been asked several times before this, but i am looking for some other kind of answer.

I just want to run a project, and it gives me this error.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-14' in: C:\Users\etc.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

I took a look at my Android sdk manager, and yes. I do not have  **android 14**.

Then I tried to find the part of project which refrences the Andoid 14. But i found nothing.

Here is my manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

**So which part or line really ask for Android 14?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Facing the same issue, I have found atribute "**compileSkdVersion**" which holds the reference to v.14 in **proguard.cfg** (Graddle Scripts, assuming you are using Android Studio 1.4).

Changed to "23" (latest today version),  error went gone.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.lifecycle"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The file referenced above is app/build.gradle

Answer (score 5):

here is the solution 
open build.gradle there you will find

```
compileSdkVersion 8
```

[image]

change it to android 6 version as shown below

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Why not just install the older SDK so you can compile for devices using older Android?

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the number of target into `project.properties` "`target=android-14`" to your available android api level in your android studio. You can see that on SDK Manager.

**Example**, if you have **api level 22** available you need to put  "`target=android-22`"

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I imported openCV library into Android Studio.

It turns out I just need to manually edit the `build.gradle` for the openCV library to match your own project.

Comment: @howdoidothis basically there is a build.gradle file somewhere in the openCV gradle project, you just need to find it and edit the usual build and compile SDK versions inside to what your main project is.

Answer (score 2):

you can find those properties in 'build.gradle'

```
// Compilation configuration.
minSdkVersion = 13
compileSdkVersion = 14
targetSdkVersion = 14
buildToolsVersion = "14.0.0"
```

You can change to install SDK version or add SDK version for your IDE

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue.

What I did to work was:

- Open de build.gradle in notepad++.
- Change the attr "compileSdkVersion" from "Google Inc.:Google APIs:14" to "14"
- Open de Android Studio and rebuild de project.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I tried to find the part of project which refrences the Andoid 14. But i found nothing.

It would be in your `project.properties` file in an Eclipse project, or your module's `build.gradle` file (`compileSdkVersion`) in an Android Studio project.

Comment: yes, you right. and when i change it to 15 or 10, it errors "Error running build: Module 'activity-lifecycle1' is not backed by gradle"

Comment: @Salman: Sorry, but I do not recognize that error. Talk to whoever you got this project from for instructions on how to get it loaded into Android Studio.