# How to remove an imported module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio, so please go easy on the lingo and navigation. I did File -> New -> Import Module and imported what I believe was an Android library project. I don't know how to find which modules I have imported or where to go to remove them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Click on the project tab on the left side of the screen, click on the project section header which will drop down a list and choose Project. Find the folder you imported and select it and hit your delete key. Open settings.gradle find the line that is similar to :
`include ':app', ':modulenameyouchooseduringimport'` and delete the `,':modulenameyouchooseduringimport'` Then go to Build -> Clean Project

Comment: Gradle Scripts--->setting.gradle(Project settings)-->remove imported module

Answer (score 9):

You can find it in:

```
File --> Project Structrues --> Modules --> Dependency
```

from the GUI, you can find a lot more stuffs with modules.

Answer (score 4):

You can go `File > File Structure > Dependencies` and then select the module that you want to delete and click on "-"

Also you can go there browsing : `Right click on your project > Open Module Settings`

If you can see it on the left of your IDE as a module the thing that you can do is `Mark directory as excluded` and then `delete` it right clicking on it.

Comment: My dependencies just list the default ones that are there when I create a new project using the wizard. I know I imported something because it broke my project after I did it with a "failed to sync gradle project" error.

Comment: I'm not getting you... can you post a screen shot please?

Comment: Actually I didn't realize you could switch views in the directory viewer on the left that defaults on Android. Can I just delete the folder it added to remove the module or do i have to do other cleanup ?

Comment: Just remove what you don't need using "-"

Comment: I'm currently using Android Studio 2.1.1. I uploaded my library module to github and now I'musing as jitpack.io. Its working. But now the problem is if I try to remove the library module from my current project it all creating a problem. I couldn't find a exclude option like you said. but I deleted from project setting top minus button. what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

AS OF AS-2.2: Remove the compile dependency from Build -> Edit Libraries And Dependencies. That will not remove the module itself from the project folder. To completely remove the module, you should remove it from `settings.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the module. Select Open Module Settings. In the popup click the red minus symbol in the top right corner. That will delete the module from your project. I've done this numerous times and can confirm that it does work.

**EDIT**

That will also give you a list of the modules that you have in your project on the left side of the popup

Comment: I just imported the module again to see if it would show up and it doesn't. Maybe its because the Gradle Project Sync fails upon import ?

Comment: @user1086516 If the project sync is failing, what is the error that it is giving?

Comment: Same error as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416498/error-failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-14-inopen-android-sdk-m

Comment: @user1086516 per that question you would need to look at the build.gradle file for the module/library you're trying to import and make sure you have the sdk(s) its referencing first.

Answer (score 0):

```
include ':jackson-all-1.9.11'
include ':guava-18.0'
include ':commons-codec-1.10'
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "myAppName"
```

in my case i delete in settings.gradle and jackson-all-1.9.11.jar and dir jackson-all-1.9.11 for module

```
include ':jackson-all-1.9.11'
include ':guava-18.0'
include ':commons-codec-1.10'
```

after my **settings**.gradle

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "myAppName"
```